# Drag a sortable item to the right

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to check if a sortable item has moved from left to right more than x pixels?
Here is a place to play:http://jsfiddle.net/qfgd9/4/

For instance if the user moves item1 more than 200px do something

```
    if( drag > 200 ) { 
        alert( "something" );
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({


});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
</div>

<div id="check"></div>
```

Comment: @j08691 I have tried a lot of things. But I do not know if it is useful to show. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/74Wjp/ Perhaps it brings more confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/262/

You can get the difference in `left` offset from `ui` object by using `originalPosition` and `position` . Hence by the difference in their values you can easily find the movement.

```
$(function () {
$("#sortable").sortable({
    sort: function (event, ui) {
        var move = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);
        $('#check').text(move);
        if(move>200){
            alert('moved beyond 200px'); //Do something.
        }

    }
});
```

});

Comment: This is perfect. I have been so many hours searching for this! I did not know and I could not find "sort:" and "ui.originalPosition" Do you know how can I learn more about this? In the official site of sortable http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ I could not find (or I did not understand) anything related.

Comment: Yes it's in documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable. ui object has these values along with other values.